# Export XP from a physical pc to virtual box

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, migration

I have an old pc with Windows Xp on it and I can't throw it away because I have programs on it that cannot be found anymore. Since now I'm using a Mac I was wondering if it was possible to export the whole operating system on the old pc (with all the files included) on Virtual Box on the Mac.

Comment: I have a theory but never actually done it so I'm not 100% sure this actually works. I would put the real HDD in your mac and mount it in your virtual machine with any OS that has a disk management solution to clone drives. Then add a virtual harddisk and clone the real disk to the virtual disk. You may need to run the windows xp installer afterwards and choose upgrade to fix the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Step 1. Use VMware Workstation to first convert physical machine to virtual machine***

https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-87B43C18-06A0-4055-B82D-EA0E81047B45.html

VMware workstation comes with a 30 day trial

***Step 2. Convert virtual machines between VMware 
And virtual box*** 
http://www.howtogeek.com/125640/how-to-convert-virtual-machines-between-virtualbox-and-vmware/

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in a free and open source manner:

Oracle has a Physical 2 Virtual tool on their Oracle VM Server iso, which will natively create an image to be mounted in Oracle VM Virtualbox.
See documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E64076_01/E64083/html/vmadm-ptov-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that with the help of any ONE of the below three applications. Please note that you can download the trial version of the application from the parent website and also the steps to convert physical pc to virtual are included in the links provided below.

1. VMware's P2V Virtual Machine Converter:
   https://www.vmware.com/uk/products/converter.html
   https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1018406
2. Oracle's VirtualBox: 
   https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows
3. Microsoft's Disk2VHD:
   https://www.veeam.com/blog/how-to-convert-physical-machine-hyper-v-virtual-machine-disk2vhd.html

Comment: This would be a better answer if you described how to use these tools and discussed advantages and disadvantages of each. (You *are* saying that the user can use *any one* of these applications, right?  It almost looks like you’re saying that he has to use all three.) Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.